# SBT How to pass input from one inputTask to another inputTask

Tags: sbt

I have problem with input tasks using sbt v0.13.2

I want to have a task which accepts input, sets that input as system property and run another task after all that, for example tests which use that system property.

I need to set system property in seperate task because overwise property is not visible during test. It is however visible during subsequent run of the  same task.

```
lazy val setEnvironmentTask = taskKey[Unit]("Sets environment variable")

lazy val integrationTest = taskKey[Unit]("Runs integration test")

lazy val runIntegrationTest = taskKey[Unit]("Runs everything")

setEnvironmentTask := {
  System.setProperty("checkEnv", "production")
}

integrationTest := {
  (testOnly in Test).toTask(" integrations.MatchModelsIntegrationTest").value
}

runIntegrationTest := {
  setEnvironmentTask.value
  integrationTest.value
}
```

This works but as you can see in the setEnvironmentTask second argument is fixed.

I have failed finding solutions. Some of approaches resulted in `error: Illegal dynamic reference`, like below where two tasks are changed to inputTasks and import is added:

```
import sbt.complete.Parsers.spaceDelimited

lazy val setEnvironmentTask = inputKey[Unit]("Sets environment variable")

lazy val runIntegrationTest = inputKey[Unit]("Runs everything")

setEnvironmentTask := {
   val env = spaceDelimited("<arg>").parsed.head
   System.setProperty("checkEnv", env)
}

runIntegrationTest := {
   val env = spaceDelimited("<arg>").parsed.head
   setEnvironmentTask.toTask(env).value  // <<<<< this is there is fails with "error: Illegal dynamic reference: env"
   integrationTest.value
}
```

It should be used like `sbt runIntegrationTest production`

In summary, how to create inputTasks which propagate input to other tasks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```scala
import sbt.complete.Parsers.spaceDelimited

lazy val setEnvironmentTask = inputKey[Unit]("Sets environment variable")

lazy val runIntegrationTest = inputKey[Unit]("Runs everything")

lazy val integrationTest = taskKey[Unit]("Runs integration test")

lazy val setEnvTask: Def.Initialize[InputTask[Unit]] = Def.inputTask{
  val env = spaceDelimited("<arg>").parsed.head
  System.setProperty("checkEnv", env)
}

setEnvironmentTask <<= setEnvTask 

runIntegrationTest := setEnvironmentTask.parsed.flatMap{ _ =>
  integrationTest.taskValue
}.value

integrationTest := {
  println("integration test")
}
```